# Confusion over ioctl() and kernel headers

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, ioctl

As far as I know, `ioctl()` is used to expose an "extended" system call interface to userspace applications. Rather than adding thousands of system calls that are unique to specific drivers, `ioctl()` is used to provide extensible driver-specific functions through a single system call.

This seems clear enough. However, I'm trying to compile my first application that uses an `ioctl()` call, and I'm starting to doubt my understanding.

Specifically, I want to make an `ioctl()` call to "sanitize" an eMMC device. Taking a look at `/usr/include/linux/mmc/ioctl.h` (or in kernel source at `include/uapi/linux/mmc/ioctl.h`), I can see this structure:

```
struct mmc_ioc_cmd {
        // Most fields omitted
        int write_flag;    
        __u32 opcode;
        __u32 arg;
};
```

From userspace, I don't have any issues including this header and passing this structure into my `ioctl()` calls.

So this is what my final sanitize snippet looks like:

```
int sanitize(int fd)
{
  struct mmc_ioc_cmd command;
  memset(&command, 0, sizeof(command));

  command.write_flag = 1;
  command.opcode = MMC_SWITCH;
  command.arg = EXT_CSD_SANITIZE_START << 16;

  return ioctl(fd, MMC_IOC_CMD, &command);
}
```

My problem is that `MMC_SWITCH` and `EXT_CSD_SANITIZE_START` are both defined in kernel headers. Specifically, in my kernel source, they're both found at `include/linux/mmc/mmc.h`.

Everything I've seen on the internet says to **not** include headers from the kernel source when building userspace projects. If that's the case, how can you reasonably use the MMC `ioctl()`? The kernel exposes the structure to pass into `ioctl()`, but it seems like you can only use the structure by filling it in with "hidden" constants hidden in the kernel source.

My current solution is to copy the necessary constants from the kernel headers to my own project, but this feels dirty to me.

Am I misunderstanding the use-case for `ioctl()`? Is this a design oversight?

Comment: FWIW, the source for [mmc-utils](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/cjb/mmc-utils.git/) includes its own headers derived from the kernel headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MMC_IOC_CMD` ioctl, and the corresponding `mmc_ioc_cmd` structure, are part of the Linux userspace API, and therefore are defined in the `uapi` headers that are installed into `/usr/include`.

The value that you put into the `opcode` field gets sent directly to the device. The kernel does not really care what it is, and cannot guarantee what opcodes the device supports, or how it behaves for any specific opcode. Therefore, opcodes like `MMC_SWITCH` are *not* part of the API.

As far as I can see, you are supposed to get the opcodes from the relevant MMC standards.

(This is not really a good reason to keep these symbols out of the user-space API; copying the kernel header is much easier than manually transcribing the values from the standard. And the kernel actually has a special case for handling `EXT_CSD_SANITIZE_START` through this ioctl.)

Answer (score 1):

If you can `#include` it without adding any additional `-I` include paths on your GCC command line, then you're fine.

> Everything I've seen on the internet says to **not** include headers from the kernel source when building userspace projects.

That advice means don't include headers directly from the kernel source tree. The `uapi` headers are intended to be consumed from userspace, and are installed into `/usr/include`.

Comment: That's not the exact case here. `linux/mmc/ioctl.h` is a `uapi` header and is exposed. That lets me see the definition of `mmc_ioc_cmd `. The problem is, `mmc_ioc_cmd` is meaningless without knowing the constants/macros that go into its fields. These are *not* `uapi` headers (they're at `include/linux/mmc/mmc.h` -- notice the lack of `uapi`), so I'd need to specifically point gcc to my kernel source to see them.

Comment: @Matt: That sounds like it might be an issue with the kernel itself.  Have you emailed the maintainer of that subsystem to ask?

Comment: @dave: I haven't. I don't spend much time in the kernel, so I thought I'd make sure I'm not misunderstanding `ioctl()` before bugging the maintainer. That sounds like a good next step.